# GAS scriplet to create an HTML column with links from spreadsheet data

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am struggling to get this for cycle to show only 1 column in html. At the moment it works but it gives me the values for the 3 columns, please check the example above:

[image: screenshot]

The columns I have in spreadsheet:

[image: collumns]

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsetest"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file">
            </span>Extensions</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapsetest" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <? var linkdata = getLinks(); ?>
            <? for (var i = 0; i < linkdata.length; i++) { ?>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <? for (var j = 0; j < linkdata[i].length; j++) { ?>
                    <td><span class="<?= linkdata[i][2] ?>"></span><a target="_blank" href="<?= linkdata[i][1] ?>"><?= linkdata[i][j] ?></a></td>
                    <? } ?> 
                </tr>
                <? } ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the inner loop over j, since there is one entry per row. Instead of

```
    <tr>
    <? for (var j = 0; j < linkdata[i].length; j++) { ?>
      <td><span class="<?= linkdata[i][2] ?>"></span><a target="_blank" href="<?= linkdata[i][1] ?>"><?= linkdata[i][j] ?></a></td>
    <? } ?> 
    </tr>
```

you should have

```
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="<?= linkdata[i][2] ?>"></span>
      <a target="_blank" href="<?= linkdata[i][1] ?>"><?= linkdata[i][0] ?></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

(Also, it's not clear if you really wanted that span to be empty, or if you meant it to contain the link, in which case `</span>` should be moved after `</a>`.)